# What is PIC code on shared libraries?

Tags: linker, shared-libraries

This is and excerpt from [The GNU
Multiple Precision
Arithmetic Library Manual](https://gmplib.org/manual/Efficiency.html#Efficiency)

> On some CPUs, in particular the x86s, the static libgmp.a should be
>   used for maximum speed, since the PIC code in the shared libgmp.so
>   will have a small overhead on each function call and global data
>   address. For many programs this will be insignificant, but for long
>   calculations there’s a gain to be had.

In this context, what does PIC code mean?

Answer (score 1):

PIC stands for [Position Independent Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code).

The word *code* in "PIC code" is redundant.